# Error when inserting multiple MySQL foreign keys

Tags: mysql

When I try to insert the current table into my table in SQL I get an error (Products table):

```
CREATE TABLE parent(

    Barcode     INT(9),
    PRIMARY KEY (Barcode)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE SuppliedBy(

    Onr         CHAR(10),
    OrgNR       INT(10),
    Date        DATE            NOT NULL,           
    PRIMARY KEY (Onr),
    FOREIGN KEY (OrgNR) REFERENCES Supplier(OrgNR)
                          ON DELETE CASCADE
                          ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE Products(

    Onr     CHAR(10),
    Barcode     INT(9),
    Quantity    INT(10)         DEFAULT 0
                        CHECK (Quantity >= 0),
    PRIMARY KEY (Onr, Barcode),
    FOREIGN KEY (Onr) REFERENCES SuppliedBy(SSN)
                                ON DELETE CASCADE
                                ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (Barcode) REFERENCES parent(Barcode)
                                ON DELETE CASCADE
                                ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

I get the following message:

```
#1005 - Can't create table '.\db_project\#sql-b58_6d.frm' (errno: 150)
```

I'm sure it has to do with the several foreign keys in this relation, I searched around on the internet, but can't find the solution.

Comment: Please show us the table definitions of the tables referenced by the foreign keys as well.

Comment: Post the `CREATE TABLE` for the related tables SuppliedBY and parent.  If the column definition of the relations in this table doesn't match exactly, you'll get err 150.  That is, `parent.Barcode` must also be `INT(9)` for example.

Comment: @Michael I believe it's also true if the other tables use engines that don't support indexes or foreign keys - although I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Hello! I've updated the tables now, just as you asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no column `SuppliedBy.SSN`.

```
FOREIGN KEY (Onr) REFERENCES SuppliedBy(SSN)
```

Perhaps you meant

```
FOREIGN KEY (Onr) REFERENCES SuppliedBy(Onr)
                            ON DELETE CASCADE
                            ON UPDATE CASCADE,
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is likely that one of the tables you're defining the FOREIGN KEYS to point to *does not have an index foreign key field* you're pointing to.

For FOREIGN KEY's to work, the field you're pointing to needs to have an index on it.

See [Mysql. Can't create table errno 150](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749332/mysql-cant-create-table-errno-150)

Also, check that you meet all the criteria for creating the key. The columns in both tables must:

- Be the same datatype
- Be the same size or length
- Have indexes defined.

Comment: MySQL will create the index if none exists. You'll get Error 150 if you try to drop the index before dropping the foreign key constraint.

Comment: Not on the REFERENCED TABLE. It will not. You need indexes on both tables. I believe you misunderstood my answer.

Comment: Adding a foreign key adds indexes on both sides. Although apparently it will not do it on its own if you inline the foreign key in the table creation...

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging that. Can pls remove the downvote? I believe this answers the question correctly.

Comment: I removed my downvote right after acknowledging I was wrong ;) Because [that's how I roll](http://stackoverflow.com/users/223339/romain).