# Composite Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, composite-key

I'm trying to create a table with a **composite foreign key**. I don't know what's the problem with this creation:

```
CREATE TABLE Album( 
Name VARCHAR(30),  
Bandname VARCHAR(30), 
PRIMARY KEY(Name, Bandname),  
Erscheinungsjahr VARCHAR(30),
MusiklabelName VARCHAR(30),
BName VARCHAR(30),
BGründungsjahr INT(11),
BGründungsort VARCHAR(30),
FOREIGN KEY (BaName, BaGründungsjahr, BaGründungsort) REFERENCES Band
(Name, Gründungsjahr, Gründungsort)
)  
ENGINE=INNODB
```

I can tell you, that the columns "Name", "Gründungsjahr" and "Gründungsort" exist in the referenced **Table Band** as the **composited primary key**:

[image: Table Band]

The displayed unspecific error is:

> ## 1005 - Can't create table 'band.album' (errno: 150)

I hope that someone of you will have an idea.

Comment: This might not answer your question, but you might find this useful.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1749332/1101823)

Comment: Good link, thanks. But other users should know: that couldn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is a character conversion issue. Try changing the umlauts in the field names to vowels.

Comment: Nice idea, thanks, but that didn't help, too. My solution was to replace the composite keys with single primary keys, so the whole thing got less complex.