# Mysql: cannot create table errno 150

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1005

I am creating few simple tables using Mysql command line. I got stock on the error number 150 while creating my Foreign Keys. Could you please help me with this one. I am kind of new to SQL.
Thanks !

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE maintenancepersons (ServiceID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
MechanicID INT NOT NULL, 
ServiceName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY ( ServiceID ), CarVIN INT NOT NULL, 
FOREIGN KEY ( CarVIN ) REFERENCES cars , 
CustomerID INT NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY ( CustomerID ) REFERENCES  customers );
    ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'dealership.maintenancepersons' (errno: 150)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mysql. Can't create table errno 150](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749332/mysql-cant-create-table-errno-150)

Comment: This link may be helpful for your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825362/mysql-error-150-foreign-keys

Answer (score 1):

You are missing column name in your foreign key constraint

> FOREIGN KEY ( CarVIN ) REFERENCES cars.CarVIN??

and

> FOREIGN KEY ( CustomerID ) REFERENCES  customers.??

Comment: I knew it has to be something simple. Thank you !